# Retrieve Call Logs Android Throught ADB

Tags: android, adb

My Phone is Android 9, I have active USB debugging then connect it to USB.
Now I want to retrieve the call log as it is deleted every 3 months, therefore, 
I run this:

```
adb shell content query --uri content://call_log/calls
```

and it give me this error

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\platform-tools_r29.0.5-windows\platform-tools>adb shell content query --uri content://call_log/calls
Error while accessing provider:call_log
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from (null) (pid=24824, uid=2000) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1966)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProviderExternal(IActivityManager.java:6445)
        at com.android.commands.content.Content$Command.execute(Content.java:464)
        at com.android.commands.content.Content.main(Content.java:690)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:341)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:15895)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:15804)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderExternalUnchecked(ActivityManagerService.java:16383)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderExternal(ActivityManagerService.java:16378)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$getContentProviderExternal$(IActivityManager.java:11954)
```

Comment: i have tried these persmissions but no sucess

adb shell pm grant com.android.providers.contacts android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG

adb shell pm grant com.android.providers.contacts android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG

Comment: Hi, I'm currently working on a project and happen to have the similar issue, by any chance was your devices rooted ?